# Is there an "append" flag for subversion folder authorization?

Tags: svn

I am using subversion with access control for different groups and users. So far I have been using "r" or "w" flags to grant reading or writing rights, but I was wondering if there is the possibility to have (or simulate) an "append" flag. What I would like to achieve is the possibility for the users to upload a new file and read the old ones without being able to modify or delete them. Is there any way to achieve this functionality in subversion? Thank you

Comment: And why do you want this? Any modification can be reverted. Subversion stores full history of changes.

Comment: because I would like (and I quote) "_the users to upload a new file and read the old ones without being able to modify or delete them_".

Comment: Ok. just write a pre-commit hook script and implement any restrictions that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @alroc is *technically* correct ("append" access-rule doesn't exist even in plans), he forgot one thing: "we can reinvent the wheel"

I see at least 2 possible (somehow partial) solutions for your task:

### Blocking workflow

**Pro**: Well scalable, zero-administration in process, doesn't require path-based authorization for work, 
**Contra**: blocking - may distract users

**Implementation**:

Pre-commit hook, which check status of all *files* in transaction (read about `svnlook changed` command) and disable commit if `D`|`M` files found (only `A` are enabled)

### Non-blocking workflow

**Pro**: non-blocking, can be rather easy automated
**Contra**: Poorly scalable (giant authz-file with **2 strings per each file** in repo), require support for path-based authorization

**Implementation**:

[Section in authz-file may refer to directory or to even single file](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.getting-started):

> Note that while all of the previous examples use directories, that's
>   only because defining access rules on directories is the most common
>   case. You may similarly restrict access on file paths, too.

Thus, verbal rule "can add files to dir, can't edit" will transform for file `/foo/bar.ext` into such authz-strings (dirty draft)

```
[/foo]
* = rw
[/foo/bar.ext]
* = r
```

i.e: you can write to dir (add new files), can't write to file in dir. And **every** added file require **own section** for disabling editing (post-commit hook can collect list of added files and modify authz-file on the fly).

This approach  does not affect delete operation, in order to prevent|repair deleting you can:

- restore deleted files in post-commit hook (additional WC on server, additional commit from this hook)
- use hook from blocking workflow (and get "partially blocking" style) for disable commits with file-dels
- collect list of deletes and re-commit files later (by hand or automatically)

Answer (score 1):

Subversion does not have such a facility. There are only two access levels - the ability to read the repository, and the ability to modify repository state. A write is a write - there's no distinction made between *types* of changes to repository contents.

If someone does something that they shouldn't do/you don't like, you can revert any change (which is kind of the point of a version control system).

Comment: yes, this is correct. However, if mistakes happen there is the need for someone to fix them, which is exactly what I was trying to avoid. I guess subversion is not the right tool, then. Thank you for the answer.